# JavaFX hard focus lost on other window area click

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I have some trouble with taking off focus from TextField in JavaFX application...

When there are few TextFields on window layout I can click on another one and it will be "re-focused", it's OK.

The thing I want to do is to fill my TextField; after I done with filling I want to click somewhere else on app-window-area (not on other TextField) and it must take off focus from my Textfield.

I've googled for a few hour and there is no result...
CSS modification will be acceptable too.

Hope for your help or ideas!

Thanx in advance.

Comment: have you tried setFocused() method ?

Comment: user43968, yes! The problem is that there additional layouts on my window... I'm bilding different q-ty of TFs, according to parameters q-ty, and they are all wrapped in HBoxes.

Comment: Where do you want focus to go to?

Comment: James_D, the trick is nowhere. Only disappear from TF...

Comment: Have you ever seen any other application behave that way?  Introducing UI behavior that's unlike any other program is likely to confuse end users.

Comment: VGR, we have the same behavior in JIRA TFs... So I need to implement such behavior in my FX app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focus has to be *somewhere*, so really the idea is, if you want nothing that either has visual recognition of being focused, or responds to keyboard input, to have the focus then you have to put focus on a component that does neither of those things.

So for example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UnfocusTextField extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setOnMousePressed(e -> root.requestFocus());
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(10);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
            root.add(new TextField(), i % 2, i / 2 );
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works!
All magic is in `root.setOnMousePressed(e -> root.requestFocus());`
Thanks a lot! :)